# Directly solving equation of motion in embedding space coordinates

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, anti-de-sitter-spacetime

If you're given a manifold as an embedding, how does one solve an equation directly in the embedding space coordinates?

Specifically, I am trying to solve the equation
$(\nabla_{\mu}\nabla_{\nu}-g_{\mu\nu}\nabla^2+g_{\mu\nu})\phi=0$
on an embedded Euclidean $\mathrm{AdS}_2$, given by the embedding $-Y_0^2+Y_1^2+Y_2^2=-1$, where the embedding space has metric $ds^2=-dY_0^2+dY_1^2+dY_2^2$. The solution should be $\phi=Z\cdot Y$ for $Z$ an arbitrary vector. (This is equation 2.3 in https://arxiv.org/abs/2010.12592). While I could solve this by reparametrizing $\mathrm{AdS}_2$ in terms of global or Poincare coordinates, it seems like it should be possible to directly solve this in embedding coordinates given the nice form of the actual solution.

Comment: Why don't you project your field equations on the embedding space and solve the projected field equations instead? The projection tensor should be of the form $h_{\mu\nu}=g_{\mu\nu}+u_{\mu}u_{\nu}$. This projection tensor is the your embedding space metric